# How to update column values to wrap everything in brackets in SQL?

Tags: sql, string

I am trying to wrap column values in brackets, so that e.g. foo becomes [foo]. I tried:

```
UPDATE notes 
SET topics = regexp_replace(topics, '(.)', '[$1]')
```

However that does not error but also does not change the column values.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Why do you need [ ] saved with data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need a regex to put a string in brackets.

In most DBMS (MYSQL, Postgres, SQLServer, Maria DB) this can be done with `CONCAT`:

```
UPDATE notes 
SET topics = CONCAT('[', topics, ']');
```

In a Oracle DB or SQLite, using || will do the same:

```
UPDATE notes 
SET topics = '[' || topics || ']';
```